# Document library "check out document" not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2019, check-out

We are on SharePoint 2019 on-premises, and I have a document library that is set up to require checking out a document to view/edit.

The library contains an Excel document, and when I open the document, I don't get the option to check out. And if I make edits to the document, the saved version doesn't get checked in or uploaded to the document library.

I'm not sure what I'm missing - any ideas?

Comment: Did you open the document in Office Online Server or Office clientapplication?

Comment: I opened it in the Office client application.  We're not set up yet with Office Online Server.